# Choose REST API or VOLLEY for Facebook Application

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, android-volley

I would like to develop an Facebook application in android and Which is compatible for JSON Parsing? Whether REST API or Volley?

Comment: Both, together. Usually, Volley is used in order to access a REST API and get data from it.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. I'm new to android.... Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also see Square's retrofit. It turns HTTP API into Java interface.

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Very easy to use and make code management a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

you can try also https://github.com/apptik/jus
it is based on volley and it has the same api mapping capabilities as retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of volly i would recommend to used [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) which is way better and faster and easy to implement.

With it you can easily parse using custom model classes and you can find lots of tutorials on that but i would recommend [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

Comment: Thanks for your Answers and they are very Useful.